# Highlight missing safe navigation/safe operator via annotations in Groovy

Tags: groovy, annotations

Is there a simple annotation like @TypeChecked that shows some warning, where safe navigation is missing in the code?

E.g. I have a field access like

```
someObject.myField
```

instead of

```
someObject?.myField
```

and I want to have the missing safe navigation marked in the first example?

Comment: Sophisticated IDEs do that. For example, IntelliJ skeptically warns about a possibility of NPE in a statement if null-safe not used.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Do you know a setting for this IDE?